# What do I need to change in my functions to be able to store the result in a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to save the result of a function into a variable and print that variable on the screen, but when I print I see "none". 
How to repair this?

```
import time;


def hours():
    localtime =  time.localtime(time.time())
    print (localtime.tm_hour)

def minutes():
    localtime =  time.localtime(time.time()) 
    print (localtime.tm_min)

def seconds():
   localtime =  time.localtime(time.time())     
   print (localtime.tm_sec)


hours()
minutes()
seconds()

var = hours()
print(var)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the return statement? How is it different from printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement-how-is-it-different-from-printing)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to return a value that will be stored into the variable.

This way :

```
def myfunction():
    value = "myvalue"
    return value

var = myfunction()
print(var)

>>> "myvalue"
```

Currently you're just printing the value in your function, not returning it , that's two different things.

*Edit:* Also note that the default returned value is `None` when there is no return directive.

Answer (score 4):

You need to return `localtime.tm_hour` not `print`

```
def hours():
    localtime =  time.localtime(time.time())
    print (localtime.tm_hour)
    return localtime.tm_hour
```

Comment: Are you know How I can change different time zone

Comment: Ask unrelated questions in a new post.

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning the value.  The script should do:

```
import time;


def hours():
    localtime =  time.localtime(time.time())
    print (localtime.tm_hour)
    return localtime.tm_hour

In [11]: var = hours()
18
In [12]: print(var)
18
```

see https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions for how to use return.

Answer (score 0):

I able to make this working with return within function definition

```
def hourMin ():
    localtime = time.localtime(time.time())
    return '{0}{1}{2}'.format(localtime.tm_hour, localtime.tm_min, localtime.tm_sec)

def dateDay ():
    localtime = time.localtime(time.time())
    return '{0}{1}{2}'.format(localtime.tm_mday, localtime.tm_mon, localtime.tm_year)
```

Calling area

```
def rannum ():
    for x in range(1):
        valo = random.randint(1,21)*5

    TimeHour = hourMin()
    TimeDate = dateDay()
    print ('Time is ' + str(hourMin()))
    path = "/tmp/temp/"
    curr = path + str(valo) + str(TimeDate)
    try:
        os.mkdir(curr)
    except:
        print('Creation of the directory %s failed' % path)
    else:
        print('Directory %s created ' % curr)

rannum()
```